# Force the UI TextBox background to render programmatic color change before Thread.Sleep in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, winui-3

In a WinUI 3 project, I'm trying to change a `TextBox` background color to green once a user verifies a project deletion by typing in the project name (similar to how MS does when deleting databases on Azure). Once the correct name is typed in, I want to signal this by turning the `TextBox` background green. The program will then wait two seconds before opening a dialog.

The problem I'm having is that the TextBox does not render the background color until after the sleep method completes. Is there a way to force the UI to render changes before the sleep method, perhaps something similar to `DoEvents` in `WinForms`?

Here's the code:

```
    private async void TboVerifyDeleteProject_BeforeTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewText != this.AddEditHeader.Text) return;


        //Initiate Delete process.
        this.TboVerifyDeleteProject.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["GreenAcceptBackgroundColor"];

        Thread.Sleep(2000);


        //Warn user and verify again with dialog.
        ContentDialogs.WarningContentDia d = new("This action will permanently delete this temporary project.\r\nAre you sure you want to continue?")
        {
            XamlRoot = this.XamlRoot
        };
        if (await d.ShowAsync() != ContentDialogResult.Primary) { this.TboVerifyDeleteProject.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; return; }

       ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` is not asynchronous and blocks the current thread, which is UI thread in this case, and that's why not only the `Background` but any UI related change won't be updated.

In this case, you should use:

```cs
async await Task.Delay(2000);
```

Comment: Worked..........